# SignalR service bus share static objects between hubs

Tags: c#, azure, signalr, azureservicebus

I m developing an application which uses SignalR.

I m wondering using Azure Service Bus to manage load balancing between multiple cloud service instances. The problem is that in my SignalR hubs, I m using static lists (for example to get the list of connected users in real time).

If I use Service Bus, how can I share these static lists between multiple server instances ? Is that possible ? I noticed it's possible with the Context object, referencing all the connection ids, but what about static objects ?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Rotan , found solution for this ?